# How to check no of messages in kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka

We are using Apache kafka with Datatorrent to process messages. Is there a way to check no of messages in kafka topic from shell command line?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate o f http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579948/java-how-to-get-number-of-messages-in-a-topic-in-apache-kafka

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java, How to get number of messages in a topic in apache kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579948/java-how-to-get-number-of-messages-in-a-topic-in-apache-kafka)

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool to get offset from a topic.

See this: [SystemTools-GetOffsetShell](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-GetOffsetShell)