# Check how many events are consumed from a Kafka topic in one day?

Tags: command-line, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What is the best way to check how many events are consumed by an application from a Kafka topic during a time window?

Currently I am doing this:

```
$ ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --topic topic --from-beginning | grep -i '2018-05-29' > kafka.out
$ wc -l kafka.out
```

Some issues:

1. It requires a timestamp of some sort to be in the payload (this is
   okay in this case)
2. It starts from the first offset so you need to
   wait some time for the file to populate, depending on the throughput
   of your topic

Any better ways to do this?  *Preferably command line as it is used for ad-hoc analysis.*

I am using `Kafka 0.10` but any answers for newer versions would also be good to know.

Thanks

Comment: In Kafka you have producers and consumers. Counting the number of "processed" events does not make sense. You can either count the number of messages produced by an application INSIDE that application, or the number of messages consumed by another application.

Comment: Also a Kafka message may be any format and may contain no date at all. So there's no built-in tool to achieve what you expect.

Comment: Yes you are right. It didnt make sense how I wrote it, thanks for the clarification.  I edited the post to specify `consumed by an app`

Comment: I wanted to see if using the `timestamp` from within the kafka metadata or similar would be possible

Comment: @Harold Kafka 0.10 includes a timestamp with every event. Add `--property print.timestamp=true`

Comment: The real way to do this would be within the consumer applications (for a consumer group) or exposing JMX on the Kafka cluster and setting up external monitoring solutions to that

Comment: Aplogize for my mistake regarding timestamp. You can monitor the offsets https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579948/java-how-to-get-number-of-messages-in-a-topic-in-apache-kafka but unless to consume the messages with a small Java program I don't see any quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you want to find this information from the broker side or from your consumer.

In case it's OK from the consumer side, you can check the following metric:

```
kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id="{client-id}"
```

It has a `records-consumed-total` attribute that indicates how many records the consumer instance has received.