# Do we need to have Kafka Consumer to get total count of offsets available in a particular Kafka Topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Do we need to have Kafka Consumer to get total count of offsets available in a particular Kafka Topic?

If not then can we use Kafka admin client to fetch the details for a particular Topic?

Comment: Do you want to get offsets using command line interface or via programmatic way(for e.g. using java) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java, How to get number of messages in a topic in apache kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579948/java-how-to-get-number-of-messages-in-a-topic-in-apache-kafka)